# switch final emitted action from effect based on payload

Tags: websocket, rxjs, ngrx

I have an app that uses ngrx

Once a client updates a product, it uses a websocket to update all clients.

This works, by subscribing to the socket, so after a next method is called on the socket, it calls an action that handles the side effects of updating

But, now when it comes to deleting and adding, I'd like to use the same socket effect but change its final action call

Or if someone can suggest a better way

Socket service:

```
export class SocketService {
  socket$ = Observable.webSocket( 'ws://localhost:1234');
}
```

effects:

```
//This is called from component to start the update process
    @Effect({dispatch:false}) beginUpdate$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
        .ofType<fromBlogActions.BlogUpdateStartAction>(fromBlogActions.BLOG_UPDATE_START_ACTION)
        .map((action:any)=>{
            console.log(action)
            return action.payload;
        })
        .do((action)=> this.socketService.socket$.next(JSON.stringify(action)))
//Calls the next method to send data to the websocket
```

//The below watches for data emitted from the websocket

//Then calls the BlogUpdatedAction, what I need is for it to call a different action based on action type

```
@Effect() watchSocket$ = this.socketService.socket$
.map((action:BlogPayLoad)=>{
    console.log(action)
    return action
})
.mergeMap((action)=> [new fromBlogActions.BlogUpdatedAction(action)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible like this:

```
 @Effect() watchSocket$ = this.socketService.socket$
.map((action:BlogPayLoad)=>{
 console.log(action)
 return action
 })
.mergeMap((action)=> { 
 if(action.type === 'BlogAddAction'){
     return new fromBlogActions.BlogAddAction(action))
 else if (...) {
    ....
  }
 else if (action.type === 'BlogUpdatedAction'){
     return new fromBlogActions.BlogUpdatedAction(action))
 })
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd already started to implement something similar, but within the map function, thanks for taking the time out to answer the question